# Articles for compound words

Tags: grammar, article, compound

I was wondering, in compound words or "complex" ones, let's say, do the article matches with its last word?

For example, "Kontrollakt". It's made of **Kontrolle + Akt**, the former being "die", and the latter "der".

Do we say "der Kontrollakt" (the one I believe), or "die Kontrollakt"?

Are there (notable/famous) exceptions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The German language is ["rechtsköpfig"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechtsk%C3%B6pfigkeit) ("right-headed" instead of "left-headed"), meaning that the grammatical properties of compound words are defined by its rightmost part/morpheme (this morpheme is called the ["head"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_%28Grammatik%29#.E2.80.9EKopf.E2.80.9C_und_.E2.80.9EKern.E2.80.9C_bei_der_Komposition) of the compound).

Therefore, in your example it's indeed a masculine word,

> **der** Kontroll_**akt**_,

*(der) Akt* being this compound's head. *Kontroll* is called the "core" of the compound, which defines its *semantic* properties, i.e. it strongly influences that compound's ultimate meaning.

There are very few exceptions to this rule, mostly they are about [derived compounds](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechtsk%C3%B6pfigkeit) with prefixes like "ge", e.g. "Geschrei" or "Gejammer", where the (leftmost) prefix defines the word's gender as neutral.

(The fact that "Schrei" is masculine doesn't really lead to a conflict here, since those words are derived from the verbs "schreien"/"jammern", not from nouns.)

Comment: Ahah well, it was a concise but nice answer. I noticed you didn't address the exception thing, but you did now so, thank you, or better, vielen Dank! :) By the way, both your links link to the same page, that's intentional?

Comment: You're very welcome - in fact, I learned something too, so thank you as well :-) About that duplicate link: I wanted to keep the link to that Wikipedia article right at the beginning, but still felt I should reference the source for the bit about the exception...

Comment: I would like to a different term for "core", that I find more intuitive: "Bestimmungswort". The "Bestimmungswort" determines "Kopfwort" more closely, while the "Kopfwort" is the primary word of the compound.

Comment: @elena: actually, the terms used in that Wikipedia article were "Kern" and "Kopf", and I just translated them literally. The folks at [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) should know more about it.